# c++ program to set up vc++ command prompt

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, command-line

I know that Microsoft provides Visual C++ developer command prompts with the standalone tools. But I wanted to customize the startup directory. I tried changing the 'Start in' property of the 'Shortcut', which had worked when I had visual studio, but that failed now(Reason ?).

Also, I don't want to take risks by altering the Windows Registry. So, I wrote the following code-

```
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
system("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools/vcbuildtools\" amd64 && start \"Title\" cd /d D:/My_Codes");
}
```

This gives the error-

> `'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`
>   `operable program or batch file.`

However, when I type-

**`C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools/vcbuildtools" amd64 && start "Title" cd /d D:/My_Codes`**

in the normal command prompt it works.
Why?

Comment: You should note that `cd` in a `system()` call doesn't change the programs working directory.

Comment: Then why this one's working-

Comment: It will change the directory from a shell prompt. If you call `system()` a new shell is opened and exited after  the system call finished.

Comment: system("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools/vcbuildtools\" amd64 && start cd /d D:/My_Codes");

Comment: The problem is I am not able to provide the title